# MethodNotAllowedHttpException on post

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

now i learn to build a facebook like web. yesterday, i can post status' but after some modification, status posting does't work

when i click submit button
it throw MethodNotAllowedHttpException

how to fix this ?
tried few way, but get the same result

form :

```
 {{Form::open(array('url'=> 'postStatus','files'=>'true'))}}
 {{Form::textarea('status')}}
 {{Form::file('picture')}}
 {{Form::submit('Post')}}
 {{Form::close()}}
```

routes :

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        $post = Newsfeed::all();
        return View::make('frontend/home/index')->with('posts', $post->reverse());
    }

    $months = [];
    foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
        $months[$month] = substr(strftime("%B", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month)), 0, 3);
    }   
    $months = [''=>'Month'] + $months;
    return View::make('frontend/register/index')->with('months', $months);
});

Route::post('login', 'LoginController@validateLogin');
Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@doLogout');
Route::post('register', 'LoginController@validateRegister');

Route::post('upload', 'ProfileController@changePP');
Route::get('{username}', 'ProfileController@show');

Route::post('postStatus', 'HomeController@postStatus');
Route::get('deleteStatus/{postid}', 'HomeController@deleteStatus');
Route::get('unlike/{likeid}', 'HomeController@unlike');
Route::get('like/{postid}', 'HomeController@like');
Route::post('comment/{postid}', 'HomeController@postComment');
Route::get('deleteComment/{commentid}', 'HomeController@deleteComment');
```

homeController

```
public function postStatus()
{
    try{
        $status = Input::get('status');
        $file = Input::file('picture');

        if($file !== '' || $status !=''){
            $post = new Newsfeed;
            $post->userid = Auth::id();

            if($status !=''){
                $post->status = $status;
            }
            if($file != ''){
                $rules = array('file' => 'mimes:png,jpg,jpeg');
                $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
                if($validator->passes()){
                    $destinationPath = 'images/upload';
                    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $file->move('public/'.$destinationPath, $filename);
                    $post->image = $destinationPath.'/'.$filename;
                }
            }
            $post->save();
        }
        return Redirect::to('');
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return Redirect::to('');
    }
}
```

profileController

```
public function show($fullname)
    {
        $temp = explode('.',$fullname);
        $owner = User::where('firstname', '=', $temp[0])->where('lastname', '=', $temp[1])->first();

        if($owner){
            return View::make('frontend/profile/index')->with('owner', $owner);
        }
        return View::make('frontend/profile/notfound');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is move `Route::get('{username}', 'ProfileController@show');` to be the very last route.

What is happening is your `postStatus` is been interrepted as a username, and failing.

Personally I'd change your username route to be like this

```
Route::get('/user/{username}', 'ProfileController@show');
```

Otherwise you'll get strange errors with this type of catchall

Comment: instead of changing the rout of user, can i change the route of postStatus ? because i want to access profile directly with the url and postStatus is just temporary EDIT : i'd changed the username route but got the same result

Comment: Only if your `username` route is the very very last route in your routes file

Comment: But I'm telling you now - this will cause issues. What if your username is `upload` or `login` or something - it will conflict with your other routes.

Comment: i'd already move into last line, change the username route, change the postStatus route, all doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Add **'method'=>'POST'** in your `Form::open`.

See, if that solves your problem.

Comment: @VensonWijaya try composer dumpautoload. I know it won't help but just give it a try.